# Encoding PCM with Opus in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pcm, opus

I'm trying to stream microphone sound with Socket.IO, and looks like the best compression codec, so far, is [Opus](https://www.opus-codec.org/).

I found [this opus.js project](https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample), but have no idea how to use it, it's in a language that I can't even identify.

Does anybody know how to encode PCM with Opus directly from the browser? In pieces to play in another client, not one big final file.

Or any other compression method? As long it works in JS.

Comment: i doubt that JS would be able to encode fast enough to stream. even MP3 cannot be done in real-time except on the beefiest of machines.

Comment: I just tried to compile above emscripten lib - its not ready for prime time.  Short of getting an asm.js version of Opus,  web sockets are fast enough to stream raw PCM just to get it up and running.  Is your question motivated more by scalability/efficiency ?

Comment: The sound is actually the final step for a chat. Already have the messages including someone typing and video for n users in the room. This part works fine, really fast, but when i start streaming the PCM the browser almost froze, in the sender and receiver, if i just through the PCM in the same browser the sound works perfectly, so i thought it was to many packedgs for the socket.

Comment: I`m working on the lib of the link, had inital problems to run the index.xhtml example, but after 2 'bugs' now i finally got to the point where the PCM is encoded.
And @dandavis , it encodes 5s of sound in 0.32s ^^!

Comment: @Moisés: that's good news about opus encoding; 15X should be enough to keep dropouts at bay. of course, phones might be a different story. have you had a chance to test a mobile device? (i've been looking for an audio encoder for some time) and if you could fiddle it, i'll love you forever.

Comment: Yeah...mobile is another story, didn't tried yet, but it is in the to do list. Thats the main reason why i`m doing video and sound separately, if sound is not good(processor or connection) the user will have the option to not use it. If works I'll post @dandavis, no love needed, a beer is just fine ^^.

Comment: you can take a look at this code, https://github.com/mido22/recordOpus, I am encoding it to opus packets and sending it to server through socket, where I am decoding it, instead, if you want, you can just forward it to another client where you can decode it, if you want opus packets just for chat, `WebRTC` already transmits in that if I am correct, you could just use that for comm...